# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' google colab

Tags: python, google-colab

Buenas amigos estoy programando en colab pero me sale el error aun no entiendo el porque

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-5eb74f12d505> in <module>()
      7     print(result.text)
      8     return result.text
----> 9 print(Traductor("hello"))

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/googletrans/gtoken.py in _update(self)
     60 
     61         # this will be the same as python code after stripping out a reserved word 'var'
---> 62         code = self.RE_TKK.search(r.text).group(1).replace('var ', '')
     63         # unescape special ascii characters such like a \x3d(=)
     64         code = code.encode().decode('unicode-escape')

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

comparto mi código

```
#!pip install googletrans
from googletrans import Translator
def Traductor(linea):
    translator = Translator() 
    result = translator.translate(linea,dest='es')
    print(result.text)
    return result.text
    
print(Traductor("hello"))
```

hice exactamente lo mismo en visual code y corre perfecto alguien podría orientarme en como corregirlo en colab

Answer (score 0):

Este problema es directamente de la api de google, prueba intentando esto:
Tomando en cuenta que estas en un colab, utiliza esto para instalar googletrans:

```
from googletrans import Translator
def Traductor(linea):
    translator = Translator() 
    result = translator.translate(linea,dest='es')
    print(result.text)
    return result.text
    
print(Traductor("hello"))
```

Con eso queda solucionado el problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución c: Pero podrías agregar el código como texto por favor? Imagina estar del lado del OP o de alguien que vea tu respuesta en un futuro. No te gustaría tener que transcribir codigo de una imagen no?

Comment: Hola, el código es el que OP comento, simplemente cambie la primera linea del import, puse esa imagen para que quede constancia que si funciona en el el colab, aun así, tomo en cuenta el consejo y coloco el fragmento de código completo.